# Insert and Delete characters/words in headline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsfiddle

I'm very new to JavaScript and I'd appreciate some help. Thanks in advance to all of you!

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KYjF9/3/

I'm trying to make that code more elegant and also valid at http://www.jslint.com/ (browser true, inherit 2)?

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Test<span class="caption"></span></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1 span.caption {
        color:rgb(224,224,224); /*#e0e0e0*/
}

h1 span.wrap {
        border-right: 2px solid #f0f0f0
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var TxtRotate = function (el, toRotate, period) {
  "use strict";
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function () {
  "use strict";
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), delta);
};

// captions and interval
var data = {
  'caption': {
    'rotate': '["communications", "design", "graphic design", "typography", "photography", "postproduction"]',
    'period': "3000"
  }
};

window.onload = function () {
  "use strict";
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('caption');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = data.caption.rotate;
    var period = data.caption.period;
    //var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    //var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
};

$(function () {
  var onClass = "on";
  var showClass = "show";

  $("input").bind("checkval",function () {
    var label = $(this).prev("label");
    if(this.value !== "") {
      label.addClass(showClass);
    } else {
      label.removeClass(showClass);
    }
  }).on("keyup",function () {
    $(this).trigger("checkval");
  }).on("focus",function () {
    $(this).prev("label").addClass(onClass);
  }).on("blur",function () {
      $(this).prev("label").removeClass(onClass);
  }).trigger("checkval");
});
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work, you need to select a jquery library and select onDomready from the dropdown list

Comment: Sorry, I updated the link!

Comment: I think this question belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
var that = this;

setTimeout(function () {
  that.tick();
}, delta);
```

Here's the only usage of the `that` variable. Get rid of it:

```
setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), delta);
```